# How to iterate over ArrayLists of different objects with a single method?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, methods

I am trying to iterate over two ArrayList fields of different types. While I could write methods for each type, is there a way to iterate over them with only a single method? I can't quite seem to figure out if it is possible to pass on a field as a method argument. In the below code, the method `iteratePhrase()` is supposed to print all elements in either of the ArrayLists. In it, [...] signifies either `numbers` or `letters`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Phrase {
    private List<Number> numbers;
    private List<Letter> letters;

    public Phrase() {
        numbers;
        letters;
    }

    public void iteratePhrase() {
        for (int i=0; i<[...].size(); i++)
            System.out.println([...].get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make `iteratePhrase` generic, that is make it take a `List<T>`; like

```
public <T> void iteratePhrase(List<T> al) {
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
}
```

You could also use a `for-each` loop like,

```
for (T t : al) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

In either case, you would call

```
iteratePhrase(numbers);
```

and

```
iteratePhrase(letters);
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I cannot call a method on the result of ```al.get(i)``` (presumably because its type is unknown?). Do you know how I would do  ```(al.get(i)).call()```, where call() is a method both ```numbers``` and ```letters``` have?

Comment: Program to a common interface, change T in `<T>` to `T extends Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java 8 stream:

```
public <T> void iteratePhrase(List<T> al) {
   al.stream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make both `numbers` and `letters` extend a common class, for example `IterableObject`.

Then, iterate like this

```
public void iteratePhrase(List<IterableObject> l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(l.get(i));
    }
}
```

or this

```
public void iteratePhrase(List<IterableObject> objects) {
    for (IterableObject object : objects) {
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

**However, `iteratePhrase` function will only accept objects, that extend `IterableObject`, unlike answer above with generics.**